# Who is a good practice to build an Application?

Tags: android

I'm recently started programming in Android Studio with Java, i don't have enough Knowledge in Building Mobile Applications.
So, my question is, if making a Class of methods for the logic of the application or make the methods in Activity Label.
Or if anyone experienced can give me a good advice.

Comment: You need to have at least one activity to start your android application. Whether you should have more activities or just fragments and create utility classes that allow you to share the methods across the app is an opinion based conversation which is considered offtopic here.

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate your time answering my question, it really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it depends on where do you plan to use your methods. Are they limited to just one activity? Or will you be using those methods across several activities? If just for one activity then no need for another class to put those methods in as you will be using them in only one! On the other hand, if you plan to use the same method in several classes then putting those common methods in a single class is better

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot!